# jqgrid sort number in descending order not working: 20 is displayed after 3

Tags: jqgrid

I tried to sort attachmentcount column in descending order so that the item with most attachment will be shown at 1st place.

The attachmentcount column is actually sorted this way: 5, 4, 3, 20, 2, 1. 20[image] is treated as 2.  Another example is: 9,5, 4, 100, 1 ... again 100 is treated as 1.

The attachment account value is number. I also use parseInt to force the column value to integer, but still doesn't help.

Please advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your data is local. It is not important if you parse the the data to integer, but it is important the definition in colModel – for this purpose you will need to define the sort type of the column.

By default if there is no definition Guriddo sorts the data as text. In order to fix your problem you will need to set the property sorttype More on this you can find [into the docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#colmodel-search-options)

The code should look like this:

```
   colModel: [
      ...
      {
        name: 'price',
        index: 'price',
        sorttype : 'integer',
        ...
      },
      ...
   ]
```